# limits as x approaches infinity of non continuous function

Tags: calculus

> If 
>   $$
> f(x) =
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & x \in \mathbb{Z}\\ 0 & x \notin \mathbb{Z}
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>   find $$ \lim_{ x \to \infty} f(x)$$

the answer says that it DNE how come ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\lim_{n \to \infty , n \in \mathbb N}f(n)=1$. If $(x_n)$ is a sequence with $x_n \not \in \mathbb N$ and $x_n \to \infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=0$.

Comment: what i cannot understand the limit means that we approach to the point along the curve so if we approaches to infinity (x becomes very large) we don't think about the removable discont. what i'm thinking about why we cannot say as x -> inf the function will always acts as f(x) = 0 because if we take for example x -> 100 then it's approaches from left f(x) = 0 (if we take one sided limit) what's wrong with my intuition

Answer (score 1):

Because $\lim_{n \in \mathbb N,n \to \infty} f(n)=1$ and $\lim_{n \in \mathbb N,n \to \infty} f(\sqrt 2 n)=0$.

Comment: Maybe with the addition $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, right?

Comment: what i cannot understand the limit means that we approach to the point along the curve so if we approaches to infinity (x becomes very large) we don't think about the removable discont. what i'm thinking about why we cannot say as x -> inf the function will always acts as f(x) = 0 because if we take for example x -> 100 then it's approaches from left f(x) = 0 (if we take one sided limit) what's wrong with my intuition